# How to free char *

Tags: c

I'm still trying to get the hang of the basics of C, and right now I'm just trying to deal with char pointers.
When I try to free up `inputFile` I get a glibc detected which proceeds to then show me a memory map and then aborts.
Why is that?

I provided all the code where `inputFile` is used

EDIT: Made the following changes in new code. Still get the same error, and for some reason its telling me the file doesn't exist even though it is there and worked before.

```
char *inputFile =  malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(inputFile, "NULL"); //NEW CHANGE
.
.
.
    if(optind < argc)
    {
            strcpy(inputFile, argv[argc -1]); //NEW CHANGE
    }
    else if(optind == argc)
    {
            printf("Type the name of the input file\n");
            fgets(inputFile, 30, stdin);
            printf("Your input file name is: %s", inputFile);
    }

    if(strcmp(inputFile,"NULL") == 0)
    { //NEW CHANGE
            printf("No inputfile detected");
            exit(1);
    }

if(argc != 1)
{
    int rows, cols, newRows, newCols;
    PIXEL *b, *nb;

    readFile(inputFile, &rows, &cols, &b);
    writeFile(fname, rows, cols, b);
    free(inputFile);
}
```

This is the exact error I'm getting:

```
example.bmp
Your input file name is: example.bmp
Can't open bmp file to read: No such file or directory
*** glibc detected *** ./bmptool: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffc4765c400 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3111275e5e]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3111278cf0]
./bmptool[0x401e15]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x100)[0x311121ed20]
./bmptool[0x4009c9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 00:1d 35691265                           /a/buffalo.cs.fiu.edu./disk/jccl-001/homes/cmanr012/Programming3/bmptool
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:1d 35691265                           /a/buffalo.cs.fiu.edu./disk/jccl-001/homes/cmanr012/Programming3/bmptool
00c5c000-00c7d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3110e00000-3110e20000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 279087                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3111020000-3111021000 r--p 00020000 fc:01 279087                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3111021000-3111022000 rw-p 00021000 fc:01 279087                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3111022000-3111023000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3111200000-311138b000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 279306                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
311138b000-311158a000 ---p 0018b000 fc:01 279306                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
311158a000-311158e000 r--p 0018a000 fc:01 279306                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
311158e000-3111590000 rw-p 0018e000 fc:01 279306                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3111590000-3111594000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
32f6800000-32f6816000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 279209                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
32f6816000-32f6a15000 ---p 00016000 fc:01 279209                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
32f6a15000-32f6a16000 rw-p 00015000 fc:01 279209                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7f3710000000-7f3710021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f3710021000-7f3714000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f37164b6000-7f37164b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f37164d6000-7f37164da000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffc4764a000-7ffc4765f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc477ff000-7ffc47800000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: `inputFile = malloc(...)` directly followed by `inputFile = NULL` will make you lose the memory you just allocated. It's equivalent to doing e.g. `int a = 5; a = 10;` and then wonder why `a` is not equal to `5` anymore.

Comment: What I ***think*** you really want is to create an empty string, which you do by using `inputFile[0] = '\0'`. Then you should use `strcpy(inputFile, argv[argc -1])` to copy the string. And use `strlen(inputFile)` to check its length.

Comment: You again lose the allocated memory by doing `inputFile = argv[argc - 1]`.  Doing `fgets(inputFile ...` will throw an exception because `inputFile` does not point to valid memory

Comment: Furthermore, you really should read about [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) because it's unlikely the string it writes into `inputFile` will be a valid file-name.

Comment: Lastly, if you always allocate a fixed size with a number that is known at compile-time, why not simply use an array? As in `char inputFile[100]`? Then the compiler would have stopped you from making the mistakes you make.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses, in response to the question above this comment, I am just trying to get used to malloc right now and how to properly deal with it

Comment: This is a total XY problem. The correct solution does not even need malloc

Comment: Please don't edit your question to change the code in considerable ways like you did. Comments and answers posted with the original code could become invalid or wrong. For considerable changes, like solving the problem and then getting problems with the solution you should post a new question. In the new question you could (well, *should*) refer to the original question with the original code.

Answer (score 1):

These three are causing major issues:

```
char *inputFile =  malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
...
inputFile = NULL;
...
inputFile = argv[argc -1];
...
free(inputFile);
```

- The first allocates memory (reasonable enough).
- Then the second leaks that memory by removing the pointer (not so reasonable).
- Then the third assigns the value of a program argument to the `char` pointer (ok).
- And then the fourth proceeds to free that program argument (Whoa! Undefined Behavior Time!).

What you were probably intending to do was:

```
char inputFile[100];
...
inputFile[0] = 0;
...
strcpy(inputFile, argv[argc - 1]);
```

Quoting from C11 draft N1548:

> if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the behavior is undefined.

EDITS:

```
strcpy(inputFile, "NULL"; //NEW CHANGE
```

This is utterly wrong. First of all, `NULL` is a symbolic constant, not a string.

```
if(strcmp(inputFile,"NULL") == 0) { //NEW CHANGE
```

This is definitely wrong too. It should be `if(!*inputfile)`. Again, `NULL` is a symbolic constant.

Comment: I know its not a string, i just did that to compare in case the inputfile name was never changed to the correct one. I dont doubt your way is better though. However I see now that that strcmp line is useless since it won't activate because Im asking for the name of it right before it.

Comment: @CrisManrique In any case, you should choose an invalid file name (such as `""`) to signify something not changing. It will work better and not make people angry when the input file's name is `NULL`.

Comment: Understood, do you have any tips for why I still get the error though?

Comment: You shouldn't get double-free with the code included in your question.

Comment: @CrisManrique Does `readFile` by chance free `inputFile`? Don't do that.

Comment: it doesn't just checked.

Comment: The dynamic allocation and the subsequent freeing isn't needed either. Just use an array (and problems like reassignment will be caught at compile-time).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That would be the best bet.